# How to return a fake/stub value for a particular selector in ngrx/store testing?

Tags: angular, ngrx

[Using angular and ngrx.]

I'm using jest and jest-marbles for testing a service.
I'm using the store inside this service. 
The service depends on a boolean value from the store (isDisplayItems).

If it is true, only then the other functions inside the service works.

So I need to mock a value so that I can make it working.
It will be possible only if I can provide a fake value like this.

```
jest.spyOn(mockStore.pipe(select(s => s.isDisplayItems))).and.returnValue(true)
```

The idea here is to return a fake/stub value for a particular selector, so that I can test service.

```
  it('should make items visible', () =>
  {
    jest.spyOn(mockStore.pipe(select(s => s.isDisplayItems))).and.returnValue(true)

  });
```

How can I achieve that?

This is my test bed setup

```
  beforeEach(() =>
  {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [provideMockStore({ initialState }),],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(FilterService);
    mockStore = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow ngrx docs how to test them: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-mock-selectors

There's `mockStore.overrideSelector` for that.

```js
mockStore.overrideSelector(
  yourSelectorHere,
  valueYouWantToReturnAsResult
);
```

for example

```js
mockStore.overrideSelector(
  currentUser,
  null,
);

this.store.select(currentUser).subscribe(console.log); // prints null.
```

Comment: Mike Thanks.

Can you please have a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888783/how-to-register-ngrx-sub-features-storemodule-forfeature

Comment: Hi, how is life? I'll take a look later today.

Comment: Yeah. Man. I'm working on an enterprise app. It has a big hierarchy. and I'm amateur to ngrx.