# NGRX Multiple store features communication

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have multiple feature stores registered with

```
StoreModule.forFeature('feature1', reducers)
StoreModule.forFeature('feature2', reducers)
StoreModule.forFeature('feature3', reducers)
```

In some cases, one store is affecting other store(s).

For example dispatching an action 'edit' in 'feature1' should trigger a server call in both feature 2 and feature 1 and should also change the state of feature 3.

Should I create an effect in every feature store to listen the feature 1 action even it's another store?
And what about feature 3? how do I change the state of other feature store, let's say after the server request finished in feature 1 effect:

```
 EditFeature1$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(Feature1Action.EditAction),
      mergeMap(action =>
        this.http.get(`url`).pipe(
          map((data) => {
            // how to affect other states from here (of feature 2 or 3)
          }),
          catchError((error: Error) => {
            return of(Error(error));
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Is it a good practice to change and listen to other feature store actions? or every one of them need to be isolated and only knows it's a own actions and state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to register ngrx sub features (StoreModule.forFeature()) for my angular app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888783/how-to-register-ngrx-sub-features-storemodule-forfeature-for-my-angular-app)

Comment: There are no states per feature, please read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61895189/13112018