# ONE NgRx 'forRoot' module othen than app.module.ts? (i.e NgRx in federated modules)

Tags: angular, ngrx, webpack-module-federation

Conventionally, an Angular/ngrx application maintains global state via NgRx's 'forRoot' at app.module.ts. Subsequently other sub states are maintained as 'features' within the global root state.

Given NgRx cli's schematic below one can apply root state at app.module.ts:

```
ng generate @ngrx/schematics:store State --root --module app.module.ts
```

However, this implies app.module.ts does NOT have to be root since it's an option.

QUESTION: Can we choose INSTEAD other.module.ts ( (lazy) loaded by app.module.ts) to store its own root state (and features for it's child modules only)?:

```
ng generate @ngrx/schematics:store State --root --module other.module.ts
```

In other words, can other.module.ts maintain its own 'root' state for its sub-module features? Note, this means there is NO app.module.ts-wide state (app.module.ts) but only other.module.ts-wide state.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to have multiple roots? Or just that one defined by that module? As long as there's only one, I don't think there's any restriction over what module defines the root.

Comment: @JeffMercado Please assume one 'root' at other.module.ts for now. Not to pollute things but if this can be done it'shouldn't matter, right?. Basically one would have multiple 'root's at each module level. Which is questionable given feature states are best for that.

Comment: You can have forFeature stores which lazy load. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/61895189/13087977

Comment: @Deitsch Thanks, but not my question.

Comment: In my applications i have a separate Redux Module which is my root and gets added in the app.module.ts. I guess one could also add that in a submodule

Comment: In Redux, there is one object that holds state. In Flux, there are multiple objects. NgRx is Redux, therefore you can't have multiple root objects.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks, but not my question. There's only one root but a different module.

Comment: When using NgRx, modules adhere to the same principle. Any module other than the app module should use `forFeature` which establishes a key in the root state object.

Comment: @Brandon, thanks. Again not my question.

Comment: @Momo I'm not sure you understand what you're asking, but happy coding

Comment: @Brandon, thanks. If you believe my question needs clarification please suggest where and I will gladly address. Otherwise read JeffMercado response. He understands the question.

Comment: I read his comment, but I don't see why you would establish the root in any other module except the app.module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238149/discussion-between-momo-and-brandon).

Comment: @Momo, no thanks, I have other matters to attend to, but it sounds like you've got the answer you're looking for.